# Display Binary Image In Webmatrix

Tags: image, razor, webmatrix-3

Could someone please point me to a tutorial/page that will explain how to view a binary image from a database (or if its simple please tell me)?

I'm using cshtml and can query the database but the image part has got me stumped.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way and hope this helps anyone with the same question.

I created a querySingle to return my image binary data in 'var=file'.
I then created the following string variables:

```
string imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(file.FileContent);
string imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/png;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
```

*FileContent being my binary data.

And finally created the img:

```
<img src="@imageSrc" alt="@file.FileName" />
```

Please up-mark if you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I use this in foto.cshtml Razor
I have fotos and thumbnails in he database. This is for the thumbnails.

```
@{

    // Cache the image for a minute
    Response.OutputCache(60);

    var fotoId = UrlData[0].AsInt();
    var db = Database.Open("albums");
    var foto = db.QuerySingle("SELECT * FROM Fotos WHERE Id = @0", fotoId);
    if (foto == null){
        Response.Redirect("~/");
    }
    new WebImage(foto.Mini).Write();
    //Geef maximale breedte en hoogte aan
    //var width = 120;
    //var height = 60;
    //var image = new WebImage(foto.Mini);
    //image.Write();//Or image.Resize(width, height).Write();

}
```